# How to Determine What Classes are Loaded in Glassfish

Tags: classloader, glassfish-3

Is there a way to get a listing of which classes (and how many of each) are currently loaded in Glassfish v3.1.2.2 either from within Glassfish itself or another tool?

Comment: Try Visual VM, with all the plugins installed.  It'll show you objects created, all gens of heap, CPU, threads, and lots of good stuff.

Comment: Hi, I've opened up Visual VM and discovered done an heap dump and looked at the classes in that.  However, it appears to only show Glassfish classes. There's not a singled instance of any of my classes listed.  Is there a different way to get that?

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about.  When I connect Visual VM to a PID I see all classes, including mine.  Are you saying that the app server has already failed and dumped memory when you start Visual VM?

Comment: I didn't realize I was looking at the Visual VM process, not my Glassfish. Got that straightened out and can now see my stuff.  Please repost as answer so I can accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  Did you get actionable information out of it?

Comment: We did.  I have some learning to make the best use of the tool, but at least I have a starting point.

Comment: I'm glad.  There's nothing worse that guessing blind, and nothing better than real data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend that you look at Visual VM, with all the plugins installed.  It'll show you objects created, all generations of heap, CPU, threads, and lots of good stuff.

I consider it indispensible for Java EE development.